# Is it possible to send data through the Chat Control (iframe)?

Tags: iframe, frameworks, chat, bots, botframework

I'm investigating a possible use of a certain scenario in Microsoft Bot
- Embed the Chat Control:
Suppose my client clicks on link that leads to my Bot Site, which contains the Chat Control. Also the link contains user Id (POST).
So it is possible to send the user's ID to Bot as soon as the customer enters the site? So the Bot can perform a specific process against this user?

Comment: Found : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1987

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only pass username and userid in the iframe due to security concerns.

Comment: you can send user name and id: <iframe id="myFrame" src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/
smilesbot?s=secret_code&username=admin&userid=1234'></iframe>

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't realize we'd added that.  :)